# Global extrema exist?- optimization

Tags: optimization, algorithms

[image]

My answer is yes because

1. The objective function -x1x2x3 is continuous.
2. The constraint(feasible region) is compact as it can be bounded between -72 and 72 (by Cauchy Schwartz inequality) and closed as you can take the limit of the sequence (the 2 norm of x) and get 72/sqrt(14).

My main issue here is I'm not entirely sure if I have done closed correctly, but any feedback is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Let $x_2=x_3=t$, then $x_1=72-4t$ and
$$
\lim_{t\to-\infty}-x_1x_2x_3=-\lim_{t\to-\infty}(72-4t)t^2= -\infty.
$$

Comment: Why exactly do we let x2 and x3 equal the same parameter t?